# What is causing a JSON parsing error in delayed_job on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am seeing this error on Heroku in a `ruby on rails 6.0.2` app.

```
JSON::ParserError: 767: unexpected token at '' (Most recent call first)
```

which is occuring at line 9 of `app/bin/rake`.

```
4 rescue LoadError => e
5  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
6 end
7 require_relative '../config/boot'
8 require 'rake'
9 Rake.application.run
```

The traceback shows it is happening in the `active_storage` video_analyzer.rb file:

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb line 156 in parse
File /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb line 156 in parse
File /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-6.0.2/lib/active_storage/analyzer/video_analyzer.rb line 107 in block in probe_from
```

And the video_analyzer is being called ultimately by `delayed_job`. The app is uploading videos, but I am seeing no problems in either the upload or viewing of the videos. So what is causing this exception? I only started seeing the problem after upgrading from `rails 5` to `rails 6`.

Comment: Can you add the code from `video_analyzer.rb line 107 in block in probe_from`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I had included the `ffmpeg` gem, on heroku I still needed to install the `ffmpeg` binaries on heroku. I tried this [buildpack](https://github.com/laddhadhiraj/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg) with the following commands:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/laddhadhiraj/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg
heroku config:set FFMPEG_BIN_URL="http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz"
```

However, the `FFMPEG_BIN_URL` was out of date. Nevertheless, the buildpack installs `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`. It can be seen from the error message, that the problem is caused by the lack of `ffprobe`, so this seems to have fixed the error message. It not clear that activestorage functionality is working completely with `ffmpeg` as the following methods have not been installed, `ffserver, ffmpeg-10bit, qt-faststart`

If anyone knows of a more up-to-date buildpack, please post an answer or comment.